# titlesec define different styles for mainmatter (book class)

Tags: conditionals, titlesec

I'm aware that the book class implements the `\@mainmatter` variable which can be used in `\if` `\fi` conditionals.

On a separate topic, I'm trying to achieve different chapter titles for front/backmatter and mainmatter while using the package `titlesec`. I want the first ones to be centered while the later to be aligned to the right.

This is the code I was using for mainmatter, which I really like (taken from this site, but didn't write down the answer ID).

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large\color{\mychapterrulecolor}}
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} %
      \textcolor{\chaptertextcolor}{\Huge\thechapter}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\makeatletter\filleft}
  [\textcolor{\mychapterrulecolor}{\vspace{2ex}\titlerule}]
```

This produces the following output

[image]

which is ugly for not numbered chapters (sorry, didn't take a pic)

If I change it to

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large\color{\mychapterrulecolor}}
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} %
      \textcolor{\chaptertextcolor}{\Huge\thechapter}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\makeatletter\filcenter}
  [\textcolor{\mychapterrulecolor}{\vspace{2ex}\titlerule}]
```

I get what I want for not numbered chapters

[image]

but numbered chapters are kind of ugly

[image]

So I tried something like

```
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large\color{\mychapterrulecolor}}
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} %
      \textcolor{\chaptertextcolor}{\Huge\thechapter}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\makeatletter\filcenter\if\@mainmatter\filright\fi}
  [\textcolor{\mychapterrulecolor}{\vspace{2ex}\titlerule}]
\makeatother
```

But that results in a centered layout with "mainmatter" (textually) preceding the first word of the chapter name (and some compilations errors, of course).

I'd like to find a fix to deal with this in titlesec (without touching book class primitives). One obvious solution is to rename my unnumbered chapters to chapter* and manually add them to the TOC. But I'm interested in a simple solution that doesn't require to change things anything else (my `titlesec` commands are in their own "mystyle.tex"). I couldn't find anything in `titlesec` documentation.

I'm obviously way over my abilities here (I think that usage of `\makeatletter` before calling titleformat is an indication of that).

Does someone knows how to achieve this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional is `\if@mainmatter`; the `\makeatletter` inside `\titleformat` does nothing.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book} % oneside is just for easier comparison
\usepackage{xcolor,titlesec}

\definecolor{mychapterrulecolor}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{mychaptertextcolor}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large\color{mychapterrulecolor}}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter\filright}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filleft\if@mainmatter\else\filright\fi
   \color{mychaptertextcolor}}
  [\color{mychapterrulecolor}\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

Some text just to see

\mainmatter

\chapter{A longer chapter title}

Some text just to see

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oops, that's the problem of copy&paste. I had tried `\makeatletter` inside `\titleformat` as a last resource and stuck in the copy&paste. I've tried with `\makeatletter` outside first, of course, and couldn't make it work. Will try your example and report back. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Confirmed. That worked. I was so scared of making a LaTeXcide with `\makeatletter` before `\titleformat` (thought it was protected or something) that I didn't check for correct usage of conditional. Works like a charm. Thanks a lot @egreg!

Answer (score 1):

If think that `titlesec` automatically replaces `\@mainmatter` by `ttl@label`

Does this works for you ?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large\color{blue}}
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} %
      \textcolor{blue}{\Huge\thechapter}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\makeatletter\ifttl@label\filleft\else\filcenter\fi}
  [\textcolor{blue}{\vspace{2ex}\titlerule}]
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Numbered}

\chapter*{Unnumbered}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As pointed out by egreg, @mainmatter still works, and ttl@label seems to be the same.

Comment: Indeed, @mainmatter worked. Sorry I wasted both you and egreg time with such dumb mistake.